# Montar Playlist Dinâmica Com Select Option

Tags: javascript, select, formulário

Pretendo criar várias "Play List" utilizando um elemento `select`, ao invés de deixar no corpo do *documento HTML*, quero colocar em um arquivo "js" *externo*, e chamar cada "Play List" através de um "Campo de busca" onde deve-se digitar a *Categoria correspondente*, então será exibida dentro de um elemento `form` cujo o "id" está definido como "playlist".

Comment: da uma olhada nisso aki http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502649/jquery-getjson-populate-select-menu-question ou nisso http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918144/how-can-i-use-json-data-to-populate-the-options-of-a-select-box

Answer (score 0):

Consegui fazer desta forma ..

```
    <br> <br>

    <form name = "playlist">

    <select name = "selecao" multiple size = "10"> </select>

    </form>
```

```js
 /* Acrescente nestas variáveis os Nomes de cada Categoria */
 /* E insira seus respectivos resultados dentro de Cada Array */
 humor = new Array("A", "B", "C");

 guerra = new Array("1", "2", "3");

 terror = new Array("I", "II", "III");


 /* Esta rotina destina-se em fazer a mudança entre as PlayList */
 /* na qual foi definida Acima, exibindo todo resultado no Select */

 function TrocarLista(formulario, listagem, genero) {

     if (genero == "humor") {

         var lista = humor;

     } else {

         if (genero == "guerra") {

             var lista = guerra;

         } else

             var lista = terror;

     }


     /* Nesta parte é feito uma varredura de cada elemento */
     /* que contém no PlayList, nos dando os números exato. */

     var numero = document.forms[formulario][listagem];

     numero.options.length = 0;

     for (i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {

         var item = lista[i];

         numero.options[i] = new Option(item);

     }

 }

 /* Agora para finalizarmos, criei o campo de busca simples */
 /* para efetuar a Busca por Categoria/Gênero se tratando de */
    /* uma PlayList de - Filmes, Vídeos, Clipes, Áudio, Músicas */

 buscar = function() {

     var mostra = document.getElementById('categoria').value;

     switch (mostra) {

         case 'guerra':
             TrocarLista('playlist', 'selecao', 'guerra');
             break;

         case 'humor':
             TrocarLista('playlist', 'selecao', 'humor');
             break;

         case 'terror':
             TrocarLista('playlist', 'selecao', 'terror');
             break;

         default:
             alert('Desculpe, nada encontrado.');

     }

 }
```

Para fazer *Teste* e ver o resultado, basta digitar no *Campo de busca* uma das *Categoria* pré-definida: **humor**, **guerra** ou **terror**

---

Não acrescentei muitos comentários para deixar o código limpo e espaçado, mas ... me preocupei em fazê-lo auto-descritivo.

> Espero que esta Questão e sua Resposta ajude outros colegas.